# Unable to find button's name with Pywinauto anymore

Tags: python, pywinauto

I have a very strange problem.
I am writing a script with Pywinauto for automatic testing on an application. I have to open a window by clicking on a button named "FATO".

For the previous version of the application, the script worked well. When I use print_control_identifiers(), I find the correct name and the button type : uia_controls.ButtonWrapper - 'FATO ', Button

In the new version of the application, the script doesn't work anymore. It doesn't find the button: uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - '', Pane

According to the developer, there was no change on this button. What is strange is that all the buttons of the toolbar have the same behaviour.

What is the 'Pane' type and why Pywinauto does not recognize the button's name and its type anymore ?

Comment: Which GUI framework (Qt?) is used? Was its version updated?

Comment: Hello. Sorry for my late answer. I was on holydays. I will see the developper next week but it seems that there was an update of Visual Studios between the versions. I will keep you informed.

Comment: Hello. I have solved my problem. The software was compiled with Visual Studio and some elements were missing in the PC target. So my script could not work on some elements. I noticed this because the script worked on another PC on the same software. The only difference was the Visual Studio package. Thanks for your answer Mr RYABOV.

Comment: Great. Please post this solution as an answer. Also please mark it as accepted (gray check box at the left side of answer should work for you). It will show others the problem is solved and there is no need to read the question.